# Are there any android wallets for Ethereum?

Tags: wallets, light-clients, android

What Ethereum wallets are available for Android? Or which ones are still being developed?

Comment: Consider making the answer as accepted, you can do it by checking the tick sign under votes.

Comment: on-hold discussion on meta: http://meta.ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/382/how-to-deal-with-is-there-productx-on-ethereum  prompted by the last new answer to this question which was flagged as low quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coinomi wallet supports Ethereum and Ethereum Classic

https://coinomi.com

Answer (score 11):

There is

[Syng Ethereum Client](https://syng.io)

> Syng is currently pre-alpha software, it is only suitable for
>   interested contributors, although it connects to mainnet by default,
>   please do not trust it with your ETH. Use at your own risk.

[Jaxx Bitcoin & Ethereum Wallet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kryptokit.jaxx)

> Jaxx Bitcoin and Ethereum Wallet by Kryptokit - This is the first beta
>   release of a fleet of versions that will be available in beta form
>   before February 29.

[Ethereum Wallet](https://github.com/lightrainstech/etherwallet)

> An Ethereum Wallet, is a simple app to check ethereum balance.
>   Which is an open source initiative from me and please feel to fork and submit your changes.

[WALLΞTH](http://walleth.org)

> native Android Ethereum light client wallet (libre/FOSS)

Comment: In ethereum wallet, I see the need to run a node, because you are using JSON RPC to access the info.   The README doesn't talk about this.

This is all obvious to long time ethereum users, but for the relative newbies out there, just what all setup do you need to access the blockchain?   https://github.com/lightrainstech/etherwallet/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=8545

Comment: @PaulS i am the author of the app, we are launching a new version with a public node and option for users to change the node if they have a one.

Comment: so you are going to open an RPC port open to the public?

Answer (score 5):

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kryptokit.jaxx

Jaxx is an Android app that has ethereum functionality. We're working on HD ethereum wallets and will soon have an advanced feature to send data and a custom gas limit to contracts :)

Comment: This is already mentioned in the above answer. :D

Answer (score 2):

adding to chris's answer.

https://jaxx.io/
jaxx wallets here you can get it for android ,IOS ,chrome extensions ...etc.

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not a separate answer