# Android Ethereum wallet for a private blockchain?

Tags: wallets, private-blockchain, android

Is there any android wallet that can be customized to operate on a private Ethereum blockchain?

I need to send/receive transactions and run simple queries on the blockchain data.

I'm not looking for an app which functions through RPC. I want an app which actually runs Ethereum node on an android smart phone.

Comment: I don't know, but have you tried any of the apps mentioned in this answer? http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/838/52

Comment: I have looked at the documentation of all those apps and it looks like they're not actually running ethereum on the phone. The app is making an RPC call to another full node to perform operations on the blockchain. Also, these are designed only for the public blockchain. I want an app that actually runs on a phone using the light client protocol. Android version was released with geth [1.4.1](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.4.1) but that works as a full node which requires space, processing power, and RAM and doesn't have the recent developments/fixes.

Comment: is there any problem to run full node on Android besides ARM architecture?

Comment: I think Light Client Protoco is still a work in progress. Check https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Light-client-protocol, and https://github.com/zsfelfoldi/go-ethereum/branches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've been working on an Ethereum Light Client targeting Android & iOS for a while now.

What you want is in [@karalabe's geth-sandbox](https://github.com/karalabe/geth-sandbox) here you will find example projects that include a cross compiled go-ethereum lib. You will also want to build your lib using [@zsfelfoldi's light-stable branch](https://github.com/zsfelfoldi/go-ethereum/tree/light-stable) which will give you access to the LES protocol so you won't have to synchronise the full blockchain on device.

There is also an [Ethereum on Android](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Ethereum-on-Android) page in the Ethereum github wiki.

If you're interested in our project check out Status.im - we'll be talking more about it at DEVCON2 - and will be opening our source around the same time, which will save you some leg work.