# Light clients for android

Tags: go-ethereum, light-clients, android, spv

I am trying to develop an android wallet using `Ethereum go` and I ran the `DroidGeth` from [this link](https://github.com/karalabe/geth-sandbox). I tried to ran `ethereum` on the `testnet`, but its taking for ever to download the `blockchain`.

How can I start `geth` in a `light weight mode` or `spv mode` as in `bitcoin` ? So that I can run it on a smartphone, without downloading the full `blockchain` ?

Is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: There are not light clients available yet; there are some progress in cpp-ethereum project.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa So how can I develop a wallet application on `android` ? without downloading the full `blockchain` ?

Comment: I have no idea on android implementation details, but [the go light client is in public testing status](https://github.com/zsfelfoldi/go-ethereum/wiki/Light-Client-Public-Test).

Comment: Might be useful: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/8389/2460

Answer (score 4):

Light clients are in the works, mostly working, though pre-alpha state. They are developed as part of the go-ethereum project. You can find more infos in the light client gitter channel: https://gitter.im/ethereum/light-client .

Further go-ethereum is starting to do experimental android and ios libraries covering a wide variety of features, among others also light client support. It already works. Please see https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Mobile-Clients:-Libraries-and-Inproc-Ethereum-Nodes for details.

Answer (score 1):

There are no light clients available yet. Some of are progress related to cpp-ethereum project.

For light weight wallet app do a hosted server side wallet. The server communicates with Ethereum node (geth). Each registered user has their own wallet contract. Mobile application communicates with the server over proprietary protocol.

Comment: 2017-01-07 Update on [Light Ethereum Subprotocol (LES/1) on Geth](https://blog.ethereum.org/2017/01/07/introduction-light-client-dapp-developers/).